# I'm having issues connecting to ubuntu 14.04 from chromebook

Tags: 14.04, server, unity, sudo, connection

```
 Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method 
 "ReleaseDisplayOwnership" with signature "" on interface 
 "org.chromium.LibCrosServiceInterface" doesn't exist

 xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not 
  permitted)
  Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method 
  "ReleaseDisplayOwnership" with signature "" on interface 
  "org.chromium.LibCrosServiceInterface" doesn't exist

  xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not 
  permitted)
  Unable to set master
  (EE) 
  Fatal server error:
 (EE) AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for driver 0
 (EE) 
 (EE) 
 Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
 (EE) Please also check the log file at "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log" for 
 additional information.
 (EE) 
  Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method 
 "TakeDisplayOwnership" with signature "" on interface 
 "org.chromium.LibCrosServiceInterface" doesn't exist

 (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
 /usr/bin/xinit: giving up

/usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused

/usr/bin/xinit: server error

Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/trusty...
```

I connect using ***sudo startunity***. Does anyone have any advice or seen this issue? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

We tried Ubuntu and others on Crouton with Enlightment desktop and got the same error. It turns out they changed dBus to use different options syntax or something like that, and they're busy updating different desktops and distros to make them work together. We discovered that only some desktops are working at the moment. The crouton page says to [try different desktops](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/3898) (like LXDE.)

The docs on Crouton could use some help.

What worked for us finally, today:

Install the <strike>kiwi extension</strike>... Rats, I mean use crouton from the crosh shell to update the chroot with the -t xiwi,xfce4,extension options in that order. Presently, the options *must* be listed xiwi first, or it [won't work](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/1279).

```
 sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -t xiwi,xfce,extension -u -n chrootnamne
```

The -n (chrootname) is optional, in case you have more than one chroot. You can install multiple distros on chroots using Crouton in the Chrome OS Developer (crosh) shell.

Here's another weird thing we ran into. If the newly-installed Chrome OS Developer shell from the Google App Store pops up with a blank screen and refuses to work, it is probably already installed. Uninstall that one and access crosh with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> hotkey. Gee, it would be nice if this was more intuitive.

Next, get the [crouton integration extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/crouton-integration/gcpneefbbnfalgjniomfjknbcgkbijom/related?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) for the Chrome browser. The link to it does not, at this time, appear on the crouton install hints screen, and oddly did not come up in the web store, app store, or google searches. But it does appear on the [Crouton GitHub Page under Prerequisites](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton#prerequisites).

Finally, once everything is in order, try starting the desktop with the xiwi target.

```
 sudo startxfce4 -t xiwi
```

Comment: The process is effectively the same for Ubuntu. Kali is just the first one we tried.

Comment: **Hellork**, then please [edit] your answer and remove the Kali Linux references and ping me and I'll upvote instead of downvote.

Comment: In case you're wondering: your answer triggered [a short discussion on meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18219/which-flag-should-be-raised-for-answers-about-kali-linux)